# How can a LINQ join select only the first record?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I wish to select only the **first record** from the '`CustomerSubOwners`' table in join query below and wondered what was the best way to achieve this in LINQ.

```
var result= (from t1 in db.Cases
             from t2 in db.CustomerSubOwners
                          .Where(o => t1.CustomerId == o.CustomerId && o.Expiry >= DateTime.Now)
                          .DefaultIfEmpty()
             select t1);
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) method like so:

```
var result= (from t1 in db.Cases
             from t2 in db.CustomerSubOwners.Where(o => t1.CustomerId == o.CustomerId && o.Expiry >= DateTime.Now)
                                            .Take(1)
                                            .DefaultIfEmpty()
             select t1);
```

Comment: I am. Perfect. Not sure why I didn't think of that :-) Thank you.

Comment: This worked great for me as well. We had to grab the first record in a 1 to many relationship. I added an .OrderBy as well to at least bring some sort of logic to the Take(1) method (so we get the first one alphabetically).